# Hex to Base64 conversion in Python

Tags: python, hex, base64

I want to convert a simple HEX string such as `10000000000002ae` to Base64.

The hex string is to be converted to bytes, and the bytes are then encoded to base64 notation, so the expected output for that string: `EAAAAAAAAq4=`

I found a tool online: http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en

But I have a bunch of HEX values that I need to convert in a script.

Comment: I had to go to the tool itself and run an experiment to see what was meant. The tool decodes the hex notation to bytes, then converts that binary data to base64.

Comment: Always try to break down your problem into sub-problems, and try to understand what the conversion actually does. The two steps involved here are both already answered widely here on Stack Overflow and elsewhere.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Python 2 has native support for both HEX and base64 encoding:

```
encoded = HEX_STRING.decode("hex").encode("base64")
```

(if you are using Python 3, see [Eana Hufwe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42230475/3750257) or [Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63595341/3750257)'s answers instead)

Comment: **WARNING!** With Eana Hufwe's answer you will get a newline after every 76 bytes of output because it converts to multiline MIME base64. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63595341/341970) for a proper conversion.

Comment: This answer is useless for Python 3, and so it should be deleted. Python 2 is obsolete.

Answer (score 37):

**Edit 26 Aug 2020**: As suggested by *Ali* in the comments, using `codecs.encode(b, "base64")` would result in extra line breaks for MIME syntax. Only use this method if you do want those line breaks formatting.

For a plain Base64 encoding/decoding, use `base64.b64encode` and `base64.b64decode`. See [the answer from Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63595341/1989455) for details.

---

In Python 3, arbitrary encodings including Hex and Base64 has been moved to `codecs` module. To get a Base64 `str` from a hex `str`:

```
import codecs

hex = "10000000000002ae"
b64 = codecs.encode(codecs.decode(hex, 'hex'), 'base64').decode()
```

Comment: That tacks on a newline at the end for some reason.

Comment: @user124384 - Tack a `.replace("\n", "")` at the end.

Comment: Yeah, it's strange that it tacks on a newline after the decode. Is it for pretty printing?

Comment: **WARNING!** With this answer you will get a newline after every 76 bytes of output because it converts to multiline MIME base64. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63595341/341970) for a proper conversion.

Answer (score 34):

```
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode

# hex -> base64
s = 'cafebabe'
b64 = b64encode(bytes.fromhex(s)).decode()
print('cafebabe in base64:', b64)

# base64 -> hex
s2 = b64decode(b64.encode()).hex()
print('yv66vg== in hex is:', s2)
assert s == s2
```

This prints:

```
cafebabe in base64: yv66vg==
yv66vg== in hex is: cafebabe
```

The relevant functions in the documentation, hex to base64:

- [b64encode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode)
- [bytes.fromhex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex)
- [bytes.decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode)

Base64 to hex:

- [b64decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode)
- [str.encode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode)
- [bytes.hex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex)

---

I don't understand why many of the other answers are making it so complicated. For example [the most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42230475/341970) as of Aug 26, 2020:

- There is no need for the `codecs` module here.
- The `codecs` module uses `base64.encodebytes(s)` under the hood (see [reference here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html?highlight=codecs%20encode#binary-transforms)), so it converts to [multiline MIME base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.encodebytes), so you get a new line after every 76 bytes of output. Unless you are sending it in e-mail, it is most likely not what you want.

As for specifying `'utf-8'` when encoding a string, or decoding bytes: It adds unnecessary noise. Python 3 uses utf-8 encoding for strings by default. It is not a coincidence that the writers of the standard library made the default encoding of the encode/decode methods also utf-8, so that you don't have to needlessly specify the utf-8 encoding over and over again.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I personally use `base.b64<encode|decode>` for quite a few years now. I didn’t realise the MIME syntax implied in the `codecs` library until now. I’ve edited my answer with a link to yours at the beginning.

Comment: @EanaHufwe OK, I am glad that we have cleaned this up!

Answer (score 12):

The tool you link to simply interprets the hex as bytes, then encodes those bytes to Base64.

Either use the [`binascii.unhexlify()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify) to convert from a hex string to bytes, or use the [`bytes.fromhex()` class method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex). Then use the [`binascii.b2a_base64()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.b2a_base64) to convert that to Base64:

```
from binascii import unhexlify, b2a_base64

result = b2a_base64(unhexlify(hex_string))
```

or

```
from binascii import b2a_base64

result = b2a_base64(bytes.fromhex(hex_string))
```

In Python 2, you can also use the `str.decode()` and `str.encode()` methods to achieve the same:

```
result = hex_string.decode('hex').encode('base64')
```

In Python 3, you'd have to use the `codecs.encode()` function for this.

Demo in Python 3:

```
>>> bytes.fromhex('10000000000002ae')
b'\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\xae'
>>> from binascii import unhexlify, b2a_base64
>>> unhexlify('10000000000002ae')
b'\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\xae'
>>> b2a_base64(bytes.fromhex('10000000000002ae'))
b'EAAAAAAAAq4=\n'
>>> b2a_base64(unhexlify('10000000000002ae'))
b'EAAAAAAAAq4=\n'
```

Demo on Python 2.7:

```
>>> '10000000000002ae'.decode('hex')
'\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\xae'
>>> '10000000000002ae'.decode('hex').encode('base64')
'EAAAAAAAAq4=\n'
>>> from binascii import unhexlify, b2a_base64
>>> unhexlify('10000000000002ae')
'\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\xae'
>>> b2a_base64(unhexlify('10000000000002ae'))
'EAAAAAAAAq4=\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

Python has native support for both HEX and base64 encoding:

```
import base64

def main():
    b16 = bytearray('10000000000002ae'.decode('hex'))
    b64 = base64.b64encode(b16)

    print b64
```

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is looking for a python3 one-liner (bash):

```
python -c "import codecs as c; print(c.encode(c.decode('10000000000002ae', 'hex'), 'base64').decode())"
```

Answer (score 2):

In python3, you may use `bytes.fromhex` to bytes, use base64 package convert bytes to base64

```py
hex_str = '01'
encoded_str = base64.b64encode(bytes.fromhex(hex_str)).decode('utf-8')
decoded_str = base64.b64decode(encoded_str.encode('utf-8')).hex()
```