# Hex to Base64 Conversion

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, base64, hex, md5

I tried to follow the few examples on web to convert Hex value into Base64 and failed. 
[Hex to Base64 convertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704327/hex-to-base64-convertion)

http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en

I need to compare eTag value of a an AWS object and Google Cloud Storage MD5 values. 
`base64(eTag)=GCS_MD5`.
`eTag:6a95b4dd5419f2ffb9f655309c931cb0` and `MD5:apW03VQZ8v+59lUwnJMcsA==`
How can I convert Hex to Base64?

I tried various examples from stack-overflow but still could not do that.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String hexadecimal = "6a95b4dd5419f2ffb9f655309c931cb0";
    System.out.println("hexadecimal: " + hexadecimal);
    String binaryNum = hexToBin(hexadecimal);
    System.out.println("" + binaryNum + ", length:" + binaryNum.length());
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(binaryNum.getBytes());
    byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(binaryNum.getBytes());
    System.out.println("encoded: " + Base64.isBase64(encoded));
    System.out.println("decoded: " + Base64.isBase64(decoded));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(encoded));
    String encodedString = new String(encoded);
    System.out.println(binaryNum + " = " + encodedString);

    String decodedString = new String(decoded);
    System.out.println(binaryNum + " = " + decodedString);

    System.out.println("ByteEncoding::" + base64Encode(binaryNum.getBytes()));
    System.out.println("ByteDecoding::" + base64Decode(binaryNum));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same library you seem to be using (assumed Apache Commons Base64, as the standard Base64 class has other methods), here is some short code that will convert a hex string to (eventually) a base64 string, and check that it is base64 encoded. It converts to the same base64 value you've given, and that the linked converter outputs:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    String hexadecimal = "6a95b4dd5419f2ffb9f655309c931cb0";
    System.out.println("hexadecimal: " + hexadecimal);

    BigInteger bigint = new BigInteger(hexadecimal, 16);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] ba = Base64.encodeInteger(bigint);
    for (byte b : ba) {
        sb.append((char)b);
    }
    String s = sb.toString();
    System.out.println("base64: " + s);
    System.out.println("encoded: " + Base64.isBase64(s));
  }
}

//Output:
//hexadecimal: 6a95b4dd5419f2ffb9f655309c931cb0
//base64: apW03VQZ8v+59lUwnJMcsA==
//encoded: true
```

If you don't have Apache Base64 imported, that's what could be causing problems. It's an external library, so you have to download it from [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi), add it to your project in your IDE, then import as in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] decodedHex = Hex.decodeHex(hex);
byte[] encodedHexB64 = Base64.codeBase64(decodedHex);
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7372374/2857319)