# How to convert hex string into base64 string without encoding in python?

Tags: python

I need to operate on raw bytes instead of encoding strings. I have seen some using encode.

Comment: Hi there! Please make sure to add more details to your question. What is your current result and what you are trying to achieve.
Also check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704327/hex-to-base64-conversion-in-python/33704357

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hex to Base64 conversion in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704327/hex-to-base64-conversion-in-python)